# InDesign: how to change direction of text on circular path

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, text, typesetting

I need to change the direction of a text on a circular path in InDesign. How can this be done?

[image: Text on Path]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- See those blue thin bars before and after your text? These will position your text on the circle shape.
- Then, see the other tiny one? This moves the type on the inside of the circle and inverts the text flow.
- Now hit <kbd>A</kbd>, drag this tiny bar around and see what happens.

[image]
[image]